# Prevent Email Spam after using reCaptcha

Tags: php, jquery

All,
I've got a form on my page that I use to send emails. On the form page I have the following code:

```
<input type="text" name="Name" id="your_name" class="contact_form_input_text">
<input type="text" name="Email_Address" id="your_email" class="contact_form_input_text">
<input type="text" name="fill_me_out" id="fill_me_out">
<input type="button" value="Send" id="submit_contact_form_button">
```

The first text box is a lamecaptcha and I check it on the PHP side to make sure that it wasn't filled out. I also hide it using some JS with this:

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery("#fill_me_out").hide();
});
```

I then have the following form validation before my page submits using jQuery validator:

```
jQuery("#contact_form").validate({
    rules: {
        Email_Address: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        Name: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        Email_Address: {
            required: "Please enter an email address!",
            email: "Please enter a valid email address!"
        },
        Name: {
            required: "Please enter your Name!"
        }
    }
});

jQuery("#submit_contact_form_button").click(function(event) {
      if (jQuery("#contact_form").valid()) {
        challengeField = jQuery("input#recaptcha_challenge_field").val();
            responseField = jQuery("input#recaptcha_response_field").val();
            var html = jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: site_url + "ajax.recaptcha.php",
            data: "recaptcha_challenge_field=" + challengeField + "&recaptcha_response_field=" + responseField,
            async: false
            }).responseText;

            if(html == "success")
            {
                //$("#captchaStatus").html(" ");
                // Uncomment the following line in your application
                //return true;
                jQuery("#contact_form").submit();
            }else{
                jQuery("#captchaStatus").html("Your captcha is incorrect. Please try again");
                Recaptcha.reload();
                return false;
            }
      }
      return false;
    });
```

If everything is filled out correctly the page then submits. I have the following check to check the lame captcha:

```
$lamecaptcha_check = $_POST['fill_me_out'];
if($lamecaptcha_check!=""){
    echo '[box style="alert"]Why are you trying to spam us? It could be because you don\'t have Javascript enabled and filled out an incorrect box![/box]';
}else{
    //Send the form using mail
}
```

To submit the form is a button and not a submit so it has to go through the jquery validation to do even be submitted. Somehow I'm still getting blank email messages to come through. Does anyone know anything else I can possibly do to prevent spam/blank email messages? I was thinking I should check the variables on the back end to make sure they are not blank but the form shouldn't even be submitted unless there are some values so I require a valid email address on the initial page. Any ideas are appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: I kindly suggest you to not inform "spam" about your checks by echoing errors or even calling an input field *"please-fill-me"*

Comment: you can always dynamically add with JS a special value to two fields, the form DOM creation time, and the submit time, than check and evaluate with PHP the time difference between those fields. Spams are usually fast. Humans are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because you have a submit button go through jQuery to work, doesn't mean the form can't be submitted otherwise.

A spambot would probably examine the HTML of your form, look at the different fields, and then just send a POST request with the relevant information. It will not evaluate your jQuery.

If you want to do something like this, set the form's `action="javascript:;"`, then update it in your jQuery to the actual value right before submitting.

Comment: Thanks for that idea. Can you control the action attribute field using jQuery or would you just update where it goes with the document.submit()?

Comment: Just use `.attr()` to set it.